# Swift, Equatable protocol bug?

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6

I am building a very simple structure in Swift that contains an array of optional values. This struct must conform to the Equatable protocol. This is the code:

```
struct MyTable: Equatable {
    var values: [Int?] = Array(count: 64, repeatedValue: nil)
}

func == (lhs: MyTable, rhs: MyTable) -> Bool {
    return lhs.values == rhs.values
}
```

Quite simple. I see no mistakes, but the compiler gives error: "'[Int?]' is not convertible to 'MyTable'". Am I doing something stupid? or is this a compiler's bug? Thanks!

(Using Xcode6-Beta5)

Comment: If the 'values' array is declared as [Int] instad of [Int?], everything works well. Why not working with [Int?]?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason why it does not work is there is no `==` operator defined for arrays with optional elements, only for non-optional elements:

```
/// Returns true if these arrays contain the same elements.
func ==<T : Equatable>(lhs: [T], rhs: [T]) -> Bool
```

You can provide your own:

```
func ==<T : Equatable>(lhs: [T?], rhs: [T?]) -> Bool {
    if lhs.count != rhs.count {
        return false
    }

    for index in 0..<lhs.count {
        if lhs[index] != rhs[index] {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: Oh! I overlooked this. Strange that it is not defined... Thanks!

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

Another useful option is to use the `elementsEqual:isEquivalent:` method available on `SequenceType`. This could allow you to avoid implementing `Equatable`, but is best used rarely as it is more verbose.

Usage:

```
let a: [Int?] = []
let b: [Int?] = []

if a.elementsEqual(b, isEquivalent: { $0 == $1 }) {
    print("foo") // Works
}
```