# Why do optional arrays not equate in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Using Swift 2.1

1. Why do optional arrays not equate in Swift when other optional types do? (I assume `Equatable` was not implemented for this particular case but I do not know why)
2. How best to equate optional arrays in Swift?

```
let a: [Int]? = nil
let b: [Int]? = nil

if a == b { // Error: Value of optional type '[Int]?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
    print("equal")
}

if a? == b? { // Error: Value of optional type '[Int]?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
    print("equal")
}

// There must be a better way
if let a1 = a, let b1 = b where a1 == b1 {
    print("equal")
} else if a == nil && b == nil {
    print("equal")
} else {
    print("not equal")
}
```

I assume it is possible to implement `Equatable` for optional arrays; however I get an error in the following implementation:

```
func ==<T : Equatable>(optLHS: [T]?, optRHS: [T]?) -> Bool {
    if optLHS == nil && optRHS == nil {
        return false
    }
    if let lhs = optLHS, let rhs = optRHS {
        return lhs == rhs
    }
    return false
}

let a: [Int]? = nil
let b: [Int]? = nil

if a == b { // Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x...)
    print("equal")
}
```

Equating an optional non-array type works fine:

```
let c: Int? = nil
let d: Int? = nil

if c == d {
    print("equal") // Works as expected
}
```

Note that I am not talking about arrays of optional types e.g. `[Int?]`.
To equate an array of optional types see here: [Swift, Equatable protocol bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25219416/swift-equatable-protocol-bug/35054988)

Comment: `a,b` should be unwrapped  `if a! == b! {      
         print("equal")
    }` and it's better if you do this , so you will not get error at run time `let a: [Int]? = []
    let b: [Int]? = []`

Comment: The problem with your `==` implementation is that `if optLHS == nil && optRHS == nil` calls the same operator, leading to "infinite" recursion. The program crashes because of a stack overflow. – The linked-to thread shows working versions.